# Rollback in sails-js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

when i delete a row from domain table.

if i have an error while deleteing the domain i make a rollback but it doesn't work.

```
  domain.query('BEGIN', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
       domain.destroy({gid: self.gidNumber}).then(function(err, result) {

             self.session.db.domain.query('COMMIT');

        }).catch(function(err) {

            self.session.db.domain.query('ROLLBACK');

        }).done(function(res) {

            callabck(result);

        });
    }
});
```